# How to give a value of class after using cut function with R

Tags: r, class, cut

I would like to change a class defined by two values in brackets by the mean value of the corresponding classes. Here is the situation:
I am using "cut" to split a variable into 10 classes.

```
data$classe_Ta<-cut(data$Ta,10,include.lowest = TRUE)
table(data$classe_Ta)
```

The result gives:

```
    > [-12.4,-7.81] (-7.81,-3.25]  (-3.25,1.31]   (1.31,5.87]   (5.87,10.4]     (10.4,15]     (15,19.6]   (19.6,24.1]   (24.1,28.7]   (28.7,33.3] 
       59           490          2783          6028          7561          7051          5090          1400           211            15
```

I would like to replace [-12.4,-7.81], (-7.81,-3.25] ...in my data frame by the mean of each class; which means by -10.105, -5.53....which needs to be calculated for each class. 
Any suggestions in how to do that would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's in `data$Ta`, please make your question reproducible

Comment: We can try `library(stringr); sapply(str_extract_all(data$class_Ta, '-?[0-9+.]'), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))`   As this `cut` output is `factor` we can make it more efficient by `sapply(str_extract_all(levels(data$class_Ta), '-?[0-9+.]'), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))` and then change it based on the levels.

Comment: data$Ta is a column containing a temparature between -12.4 and 33.3 (about 30688 rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `str_extract` to extract all the numeric elements, convert the string to `numeric`, get the `mean`.

```
v1 <-  sapply(str_extract_all(levels(data$classe_Ta), 
      "-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?"), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))

data$Mean <- v1[as.numeric(data$classe_Ta)]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data <- data.frame(Ta = sample(-50:100, 20, replace=TRUE))
data$classe_Ta<-cut(data$Ta,10,include.lowest = TRUE)
```

Comment: This looks pretty good! Thank you. Only one thing is quite strange: two of the classes are (10.4,15]   and  (15,19.6], for these two classes, the mean is not well calculated, it gives actually the limit of the class, i.e: 10.4 and 19.6 instead of 12.7 and 17.3 respectively. Is it because the limit 15 is an integer? For the other classes, it is perfect. how to manage when one of the limit is an integer then?

Comment: @virginie Thanks for the comment.  Yes, there was a bug in the code.  Can you check the updated one? i.e. `str1 <- "(10.4,15]";sapply(str_extract_all(str1, "-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?"), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
#[1] 12.7`

Comment: Wonderful! It works perfectly. I will check the str_extract_all function to understand it better.